# Is it possible for PowerShell to access embedded resources from an executable?

Tags: c#, powershell, extract, executable, embedded-resource

Given I have an executable (MyProgram.exe) with an embedded resource / manifest file (in this case). Is it possible to programmatically extract the file?

Thanks,

N.B. Needs to be PowerShell 2.0 compatible

Comment: I haven't checked it but it should be because powershell is based on .net and can use every .net object. So logically it should be possible.